# How to position popup window in excel vsto application

Tags: c#, winforms, vsto

I have much research on this, but I failed anyway.
I am working on Excel VSTO Add-in where I have a popup form. This popup form is of type Form. It opens up whenever a button is clicked. The problem is I can't position it just right under the button clicked.

Tried already:

- Getting button Location property and setting it to the form's
  location. However when I set form's location it is regarded as
  desktop location.
- Cursor Position. It's working somehow better. But my button is on the edge of the screen, so when the user click the edge of the
  button, the form is almost not seen as it goes out of desktop's
  visibility

Answer (score 0):

As soon as posting the question, I got the answer. I'm posting my answer as it may help others

I found to location of the button relative to screen by:

```
var location = button.Parent.PointToScreen(button.Location);
```

and gave it the location of the popup form by

```
this.DocumentOptions = new HeaderDocumentOptions
        {
            Visible = true,
            StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual,
            Location = new Point(location.X - 130 + btnDocumentOptions.Width, location.Y + btnDocumentOptions.Height)
        };
```

Note: I subtracted and added some values to its X as to satisfy my needs